# What does the ellipsis in Machado's poem 'Pegasos, lindos pegasos' mean?

Tags: poetry, spanish-language, antonio-machado

What does the ellipsis in Machado's poem ['Pegasos, lindos pegasos'](http://bitacorauriarte.blogspot.com/2012/03/comentario-de-pegasos-lindos-pegasos-de.html) mean? I don't know what all those dots represent. Maybe it is something specific I'm not aware of. Here is the poem.

> Pegasos, lindos pegasos,
> caballitos de madera.
> ...................................
> Yo conocí, siendo niño,
> la alegría de dar vueltas
> sobre un corcel colorado,
> en una noche de fiesta.
> En el aire polvoriento
> chispeaban las candelas,
> y la noche azul ardía
> toda sembrada de estrellas.
> ¡Alegrías infantiles
> que cuestan una moneda
> de cobre, lindos pegasos,
> caballitos de madera!

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! One thing I noticed when looking for an online link to the poem is that the ... is not in the same place for every transcription. [This one](https://www.conmishijos.com/actividades-para-ninos/cuentos/pegasos-lindos-pegasos-poesia-de-antonio-machado-para-ninos/) puts it at the end of the second line, but doesn't use it to divide two stanzas, and [this one](https://www.mundoprimaria.com/lecturas-para-ninos-primaria/pegasos) is simply missing those first two lines altogether. Where did your copy of the poem come from?

Comment: http://bitacorauriarte.blogspot.com/2012/03/comentario-de-pegasos-lindos-pegasos-de.html. I also found it written like that in a serious anthology.

Comment: The version at [Wikisource](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/Pegasos,_lindos_pegasos) has the epigraph from Paul Verlaine: *Tournez, tournez, chevaux de bois.* it seems to me that the first two lines might be a very loose recapitulation of this verse of Paul Verlaine. Paul Verlaine is clearly describing a merry-go-round, and [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/spanish-english/caballito) says *caballitos* can mean *merry-go-round*.

Comment: Ok, but what on earth are those dots?

Comment: Possibly a literary convention equivalent to three centered asterisks or other dingbats to indicate "Break here!"

Comment: I'd agree with Mary — it's turning from a musing or observation about carousel horses to a first person memory, so it's showing the disconnect.